# TruncateHtml doesn't work on github blog

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll, truncate, github-pages

I'm writing a blog on .github.io

As Github recommends, I use the Jekyll structure. I want to post my blog in the form of Markdown but I also want my index to show the truncated **raw** text of posts **without rendering and auxiliary symbol**.

I wrote `<div>{{ post.content |truncatehtml |truncatewords: 30 }}</div>`. It works well on localhost but doesn't work on my blog http://piscesdream.github.io/

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `truncatehtml` functionality is being provided a plug-in, plug-ins are not supported when using GitHub pages, try something like `<div>{{ post.content | strip_html | truncatewords:30 }}</div>` instead.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot. Is `strip_html` a standard filter in Jekyll?

Comment: Glad that worked, `strip_html` is part of the standard Liquid Markup. Here is a [good introduction](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers) which helped me alot when doing my own site.